# Logic apps Ip Restriction

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-logic-apps, azure-app-service-plans

I need to set my Azure app service's outbound IPs to my logic app IP restriction whitelist, so that nobody can call the logic app except through my api app.
But the problem is that logic app restriction list only accepts IPs in range format
`x.x.x.x/x`
and I need to allow a set of 5 different IPs which is my API's app outbound IPs.
[App Service Ips](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hS8XQ.png)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation:

- [Secure access in Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-securing-a-logic-app#restrict-incoming-ip-addresses)

Logic App allows you to specify ip address + network mask.

/32 is a network mask of 255.255.255.255

So xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/32 = ip address of xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

if you use the /32 network mask, you will be able to add the specific ip addresses you want.

Comment: What do you mean by not working ? You can't invoke your logic app from function after adding the 5 IP addresses?

Comment: i can`t call the logic app endpoint from the app service app when i add it`s ips followed by /32

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it's hard to assign a dedicated static outbound IP to a Logic App now.

Here is an [issue](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/18545683-provide-a-way-to-assign-a-dedicated-static-outboun) that you could vote up it to promote the realization of this feature.

Comment: this is not related to my question please read the post again!